# Dropwizard metric for proportion of time a thread is doing 'work'

Tags: multithreading, dropwizard, metrics, capacity

I would like to use dropwizard to report on the proportion of time a particular thread is doing 'work' and not just blocking.

A bit of background - I have a heavily multi-threaded application, with many threads passing data between themselves using blocking data transfer queues. I want to find bottlenecks during execution; what proportion of time each thread is taking doing actual work, and not just blocking on receiving the next piece of data, so I can identify which thread is the bottleneck during execution.

Basically, measuring (time taken to do an op)/(total time), split into 1 min/5 min/15 min/all time averages. How can I do this using dropwizard?